# django project deploy with apache, the apache is running, but its shows error and dependency is already install

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, amazon-web-services

Django project deploy with apache, the apache is running, but its shows error and dependency is already install

```
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115495 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, i$
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115497 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]     django.setup(set_prefix=False), referer: http://13.127.165.50/en/admin/
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115501 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in$
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115503 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS), referer: http://13.127.165.50/en/ad$
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115507 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 8$
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115509 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry), referer: http://13.127.165.50/en/admi$
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115513 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94,$
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115515 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]     module = import_module(entry), referer: http://13.127.165.50/en/admin/
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115518 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module, $
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115521 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level), referer: http:$
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115524 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import, referer: http$
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115534 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load, referer: h$
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115538 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked, r$
[Wed Dec 12 10:59:32.115550 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 20200:tid 140575906928384] [client 103.3.228.58:42384] ImportError: No module named 'djangocms_text_ckeditor', referer: http://13.127.$
```

Comment: the error is ImportError: No module named 'djangocms_text_ckeditor' but it is install

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try to run the shell on the server, e.g. `./manage.py shell`?

Comment: yes get the same error

Comment: when i do shell i did not get the error, while i start apache, and check the link in browser it show me Internal Server Error, and in apache log shows that's error

Comment: the error is solve

Comment: I'm getting 500 Internal Server errors when I try to make an HTTP POST to a specific address in my app. I've looked into the server logs in the custom log directory specified in the virtual hosts file, but the error doesn't show up there so debugging.

How do I cause Apache to log Internal 500 errors into the error log?